# Is 'for an interval' okay?

Tags: prepositions, expressions

Suppose there is a certain condition with the time interval, only during which it holds. For example,

> Condition: High humidity / Interval: June to September

What I want now is describing that 'there are some texts like above', but
I prefer it as concise as possible as in the business context. I guess it is grammatically safe to write as below,

> A condition with the interval during which it holds.

but can I shrink it down further by using 'for' instead of 'during'?

> A condition with the interval that it holds for.

Answer (score 1):

> A condition with the interval during which it holds.

> A condition with the interval that it holds for.

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I would avoid using either of these forms. The reason is that it's better to have simple and direct sentences where possible. Using the pronoun "it" in these sentences makes them particularly difficult to understand. I'd drop the "it" and explicitly refer to what you're discussing.

You also don't need to use the words "condition" or "interval" in this case because if you write "weather" and "from June to September" instead, readers will understand more easily. These are something like what I would write:

> The humidity remained high from June to September.

> The weather remained ______ (hot, cold, humid, etc.) from June to September. These conditions returned in July the following year.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer this question myself. According to the Google Trend comparison, I guess my original thought (i.e., 'during the interval' is grammatical) is wrong. 'For the interval' is the most idiomatic usage, at least according to the search result.

The possible rationales behind this would be; i) an interval is a sort of like an *amount* of time, so using 'for' would make more sense than using 'during', which should be used for a *period* of time that begins and ends at a certain point of time. ii) **The** interval is preferred over **an** interval because basically something is more or less done in a *specific* amount of time. I guess the second rationale is not mandatory, but rather depends on the context.

[image]